# Jasper Ireport. Problemas con sub reportes

Tags: ireport, jasper

Tengo un reporte padre el cual llame a un sub reporte el cual lo que hace es mostrarte los nombres de unos campos.  Cuando el reporte general solo tiene una pagina el subreporte me muestra los nombres de los campos, pero cuando el reporte general tiene mas de una pagina solo me muestra la información en la primera pagina pero en el resto de paginas no.  He intentado colocar este sub reporte en la banda del detalle del reporte principal, al igual que en la banda del encabezado del reporte principal, pretendiendo que con esto se repita, pero hasta el momento no he podido obtener el resultado esperado.

Gracias de antemano por la atención prestada.

Comment: Puede que se esté repitiendo, pero esté iterando de una forma que no esperas, etc. Creo que es importante que compartas el xml que define el reporte

Comment: Prueba agregando una segunda banda de detalle para el subreporte.